# converting Dynamic URLs to directory like url

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

Of.  I have found plenty of resources on converting specific url strings (domain.com/?hello=world to domain.com/hello/world )  but what I am looking for is a way to dynamically convert ANY url that I pass to a directory stucture, or I should say, if you go to domain.com/hello/world then it automatically passes to my php script: domain.com/?hello/world .  I need this to be completely dynamic so that anything that I send will be converted.

i.e.

domain.com/login/register is seen by my php script as domain.com/?login=register
domain.com/login = domain.com/?login=
domain.com/hello/world = domain.com/?hello=world
domain.com/pages/about = domain.com/?pages=about
domain.com/about = domain.com/?about

and more importantly, I need to be able to do this..

domain.com/login/register/confirm/6473440367233483730126345 = domain.com/?login=register&confirm=6473440367233483730126345
domain.com/posts/categories/general = domain.com/?posts=categories&general

basically each odd directory is the get Key and each even is a value (if any is present).  This needs to go on for as long as necessary and not be limited to only 2 or 3 key/value strings.

Edit:  This is what I originally came up with (seee below for final solution).

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

index.php

```
$ReqURI = array_filter(explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
```

And this is the final solution thanks to a few threads here and some tweaking.

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

index.php

```
if(preg_match_all('([^/]+)', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches)){
    $val = array();
    $key = array();
    foreach ($matches[0] as $i => $req){
        if($i % 2){
            $val[] = $req;
        }else{
            $key[] = $req;
        }
    }
    if(count($val) < count($key)){
    $val[] = '';
    }
    $params = array_combine($key,$val);
    print_r($params);
}
```

Comment: Lawrence, see my edits above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Nev Stokes`'s PHP code from above and try to create the .htaccess file like this, so that it won't break other ( static ) resources:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR] # 1. is this a request to static file ?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR] # 2. if not, is it a request to a symlink ?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d      # 3. if not, is it a request to a directory ?
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]               # 4. if true ( any of those three above ), serve the request normally and STOP ( because of L  `last` flag ).
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]       # 5. if neither 1,2,3 are true, redirect to index.php
```

Comment: Can you explain the difference between your htaccess and the one I came up with above?

Comment: nevermind.  found a great cheatsheet to explain things: http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet/

Comment: Yea I still have a couple questions.. like why the two RewriteRules?  i.e. 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
and i learned from here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html
helped with the rest of the details for your solution.

Comment: Edited post with full explanation on what's happening

Answer (score 2):

If you want to rewrite everything then this is really quite simple.

In your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* serve.php
```

In serve.php this code will create an array from the URL with key/value as you asked for:

```
if (preg_match_all('#([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))?#', trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'), $matches)) {
    $params = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
    var_dump($params);
}
```

Comment: this will break all the css and js and images ... files

Comment: The OP specifically asked to convert any URL. Their asset files could well be hosted on another server or CDN.

Comment: Not assuming - working to a brief. Go read the question again: "way to dynamically convert ANY url"

Comment: You are both right.  I did say any URL but I was referring to specifically dynamic URLS, i.e. /?hello=world turns to /hello/world off of the main index.php, thought that should have been clear by what I wrote above :P  This solution is on the right track though.  see my above edits for details.  the php here will def work better than the one I originally came up with.  now am just working out the details of the .htaccess file to allow for if the files exist.

Comment: the php part of this works perfectly.  as for the .htaccess tXK's solution is key.

Comment: OK.  basically ran into an issue with this solution Nev, basically if I have only 1 level i.e. domain.com/login  this solution doesn't work because the pregmatch does not catch a pair.  so see above what i did to work around this.  basically I take all instances individually and then loop through even/odd pairing and merging the two arrays.  if (as is sometimes the case) the keys and values not equal, I add 1 position to the values (keys will always be equal to or greater since they come first).

Comment: Hey JSD, I've tweaked the regex to account for this — lax of me, sorry! I've also trim'ed any trailing or leading / that could lead to empty entries in the array

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good tutorial for writing dynamic urls. and your particular problem is posted there.

[.htaccess tricks and tips](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php)